# javascript get value from external PHP value

Tags: php, javascript, audio-player

So basically i have a js file which looks like:

```
    var player = $("#zen .player");
        
    player.jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: ""
            });
        },
        swfPath: "",
        supplied: "mp3"         
    });
```

And i want to be able to set the mp3 value of the js from a php value (e.g. `$h->post->vars['audio']`.
So something like `mp3: $h->post->vars['audio']`

**The mp3 value must remain between the double-quotes for some reason in order to work.**

I am using [Zen Audio Player](http://lab.simurai.com/ui/zen-player/).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dup of [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (including escaping newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/), and many, *many*, ***MANY*** others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, to put a PHP value in JavaScript:

```
var something = <?php echo json_encode($php_var); ?>;
```